# nil Validation fails when importing contact with email address

Tags: ios, swift

it is me again, i am trying to import the contacts details to my app (with the user permission of course).  And I am stuck when I am trying to import the emails of the contact and the contact has not email setup.

This is the code that i am using in swift.
[image]

What am I doing wrong? or what am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It doesn't look like that "if" should be on the first line.  And if so, the syntax looks incorrect. (I haven't dabbled with Swift much).

Answer (score 0):

Hi after review my code found the correct way to do this. Here is a copy of the code that I did.

[image]